# Filtering and modifying immutable sequence in loop and have changes effective in subsequent filter calls

Tags: scala, collections

I guess I kinda murdered the title but I could not express it another way.

I have a trait like this:

```
trait Flaggable[T <: Flaggable[T]] { self : T => 
  def setFlag(key: String, value: Boolean): T
  def getFlag(key:String): Boolean
}
```

This trait itself is not that important, but main thing here is class implementing it should be immutable as `setFlag` returns a new instance. Example class extending this trait:

```
class ExampleData(val flags: Map[String, Boolean] = Map()) 
    extends Flaggable[ExampleData] {

  def setFlag(key: String, value: Boolean): ExampleData = 
     new ExampleData(flags + (key->value))
  def getFlag(key:String): Boolean = flags(key)

}
```

While iterating over collection I set flags on elements and I want those flags to be effective in subsequent iterations. Something like

```
val seq: Seq[ExampleData] = ???
seq.view.filter(el => !el.getFlag("visited")).foreach { el =>
    // do things that may set flag visited to true in elements
    // further in the seq, if that happens I do want those
    // elements to be filtered        
}
```

Now AFAIK, one option is to make `seq` mutable and assign new instances returned from `setFlag` to `seq`. Another option is to make whole flaggable thing mutable and modify instances in place in collection. Do I have any other option without making either of these (class and collection) mutable? I do not even know how can I modify and filter at the same time in that case.

I guess I should explain my situation more. Specifically, I am trying to implement dbscan clustering algorithm. I have a function that can return distance between two data points. For each data point, I need to get data points that is closer than an epsilon to that data point and mark those visited. And I do not want to process data points that is marked visited again. For example, for data point with index 0, the index list of data points closer than epsilon might be [2, 4, 5]. In this case I want to flag those data points as visited and skip over them without processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use map instead of foreach and replace the order of the functions:

```
seq.view.map { el =>
    // do things that may set flag visited to true and return the new 
    // or e1 if no change needed.
}.filter(el => !el.getFlag("visited"))
```

---

*Update*:
Since the filter and the update related to each other, use mutable collection. I prefer that than mutable data objects, since it can be limit only to that scope. (e.g. use `seq.to[ListBuffer]`).  after you done, all the mutations gone.... This allow keep the mutable code locally.
Nevertheless, depends on your algorithm, there may be a better collection for that, like [Zipper](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Zipper.html).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think this would end up with me processing every element in seq. I want to skip over elements I marked visited in one of previous iterations. I edited my question to explain my case more specifically.

Comment: @mefu, I update the answer based on you update and comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could extract a function to handle what is done inside your foreach with a signature like:

```
def transform(in: ExampleData): ExampleData
```

with that you could use a for comprehension:

```
for {
  elem <- seq if !elem.getFlag("visited")
  result = transform(elem) if result.getFlag("Foo")
} yield result
```

If you have multiple operations you can just append:

```
for {
  elem <- seq if !elem.getFlag("visited")
  r1 = transform(elem) if r1.getFlag("Foo")
  r2 = transform2(r1) if r2.getFlag("Bar")
} yield r2
```

The result would be a new `Seq` of new `ExampleData` according to the transformations and filters applied.

In general, if you want to both filter and process elements you would usually use the `collect` function and possibly chain them:

```
seq.collect { 
  case elem if !elem.getFlag("visited") => transform(elem) 
}.collect { 
  case elem if elem.getFlag("Foo") => transform2(elem) 
}.filter(_.getFlag("Bar")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. My main problem here is while looping over i th element I might modify (i+5)th element. And in that case, I want i+5 th element to get filtered and not get processed because processing is kinda costly. In case of your answer, it would be like I want to modify further elements in transform(elem) function. I am sorry if I could not understand your answer completely, I am not well versed in Scala.